# python boto3 put_item fails when using local dynamodb container

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am testing out boto with a local dynamodb docker container, I get this error while putting a new item into the table. The table exists.

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3
import os

os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "localaccesskey"
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "password"

conn = boto3.resource('dynamodb', aws_access_key_id="localaccesskey",  aws_secret_access_key="password", region_name='eu-west-1', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")
print(list(conn.tables.all()))


table = conn.Table('Movies')
table.put_item(
   Item={
        'username': 'janedoe',
        'first_name': 'Jane',
        'last_name': 'Doe',
        'age': 25,
        'account_type': 'standard_user',
    }
)
```

error:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/kshk/PycharmProjects/Skulldogo/eli.py
[dynamodb.Table(name=u'Movies'), dynamodb.Table(name=u'devApiConfig'), dynamodb.Table(name=u'devApiKeys'), dynamodb.Table(name=u'devObjectCache'), dynamodb.Table(name=u'devSessionCache'), dynamodb.Table(name=u'test'), dynamodb.Table(name=u'test1'), dynamodb.Table(name=u'test10')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kshk/PycharmProjects/Skulldogo/eli.py", line 52, in <module>
    'account_type': 'standard_user',
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 518, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 258, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 548, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One of the required keys was not given a value
```

any ideas???

Comment: can you change that localhost to 127.0.0.1 and then see if it works?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, I also did dynamodb setup locally with docker, I am giving both partition and sort key of type string (which I also doubled checked the type that I'm trying to store which is <class 'str'> but I get the same error. code looks like more or less like the one of the question, anybody has any idea on why this could happen?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not autogenerate the ID when creating new records. Make sure to supply the hash key.

Oh and the range key too when defined.